# How to record everything that goes in my EarPods on OS X Yosemite?

Tags: software-recommendation

I would like to record what I hear and what I say from my EarPods, I thought I would use Soundflower but unfortunately it looks like it isn't compatible at all with Yosemite.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [SoundSiphon](http://staticz.com/soundsiphon/) as a Soundflower replacement. It works well, but occasionally it produces system log messages (which are merely annoying).

I'm not sure about recording what goes into the EarPods mic at the same time, but by itself it should work without needing additional software.

Answer (score 1):

You can record your Mac's sound output by using AudioCity :

http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/tutorial_recording_computer_playback_on_mac.html